# how to make an array of values from a regular expression in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

For instance,

```
var str = '<a href="one">foo</a>   <a href="two">bar</a> ...';
var reg = /href\="([^"]*)"/g;

console.log(str.match(reg));
```

will output **[ 'href="one"', 'href="two"' ]**

but i want **[ 'one', 'two' ]** (only the value between the parenthesis in the *reg*).

Is it possible directly from a function in JavaScript without writing tone of codes ?

Comment: Just use the regex in a loop calling `RegExp#exec(s)` and access the `match[1]` values. There is no method that will allow to get capture group contents as a list in JS.

Comment: didn't realize the function had an iterative-behavior, thanks.

Comment: As a hack, you can actually use `match` with the regex and then post-process the items within `map` (since the length of `href="` and `"` at the end is known).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes i just thought about that but the marked answer is great